# Uncaught TypeError: web3.currentProvider.sendAsync is not a function

Tags: web3js

Calling `web3.currentProvider.sendAsync` raise an exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: web3.currentProvider.sendAsync is not a function

Note: I faced this error when using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@digix/tempo. However, `sendAsync` is not a function inside `web3.currentProvider` when trying to check this with Web3 v1.0

Answer (score 8):

Actually `web3.currentProvider.sendAsync` is depricated in Web3 v1.0 and it is replaced with `web3.currentProvider.send`.

So simply replace `web3.currentProvider.sendAsync` with `web3.currentProvider.send` when using Web3 v1.0.

For my case, I forked the "DigixGlobal tempo" repository from https://github.com/DigixGlobal/tempo, modified the code and made [a pull request](https://github.com/DigixGlobal/tempo/pulls).

Comment: is there a working example for signing a string with a user friendly message? these are also outdated and don't work https://github.com/danfinlay/js-eth-personal-sign-examples

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who arrived here from having a `solidity-coverage` error when running `truffle coverage` and having it fail verus `truffle test` and having that succeed, the answer is correct, change `.sendAsync` to `.send`. It takes longer to run, but works.

It seems like the injected web3 instance during the coverage plugin is slightly different to the web3 instance during `truffle test`.